# displaying image and mathematical formulae in div using vue js which is saved by ckeditor

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor4.x

i am using ckeditor to insert mathematical formulae and images in database. i am getting the following response from database..

for mathematical formula...

```
{
"questionM_ref_id": "c6L5SIUqgRC9ZV2Z",
"subject_chapter_id": 1,
"question": "<span style=\"font-size:12pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;times new roman&quot;,serif\"><strong><span style=\"font-family:symbol\">\\</span> <span class=\"math-tex\">\\(x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}\\)</span></strong></span></span><br />\n<span style=\"font-size:12pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;times new roman&quot;,serif\"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src=\"file:///c:\\users\\rajesh\\appdata\\local\\temp\\msohtmlclip1\\01\\clip_image006.gif\" style=\"height:17px; width:60px\" /></strong></span></span>",
"marks": "2",
"answer": "Abd",
```

}

for image and for image...

```
{
"questionM_ref_id": "gdRWNUbgki9NJWSI",
"subject_chapter_id": 1,
"question": "<img alt=\"\" border=\"0\" hspace=\"0\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" style=\"border:0px solid black; height:512px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-top:0px; width:512px\" vspace=\"0\" />",
"marks": "2",
"answer": "Hhghj",
```

}

the image is in base64 format....
now in my vue i am doing the following

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div v-html="questions.question"></div>
</div>
```

i am using v-html because i am getting questions in other language like hindi and after using v-html all other language fonts are being showed in a div but image and mathematical formulas are not being displayed... for reference image of mathematical formula is...

[mathematical formula displaying in wrong format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpOn5.png)

and image is not showing at all

[no image is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxmfi.png)

on inspecting image element i am getting

```
<img alt="" border="0" hspace="0" src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="border:0px solid black; height:512px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-top:0px; width:512px" vspace="0">
```

but its not displayng the image

please help me.. how can I display them correctly in div... for fomulae i am using mathjax in my ckeditor...

Answer (score -1):

i resolved it by using a different plugin, other than mathax, and base64 image up loader. i replaced them with Equation Editor for maths formula and kcfinder for uploading image. now its working perfectly.